# sendBroadcast not working with custom intent filter

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth-lowenergy, intentfilter

I am trying to modify the BluetoothLeGatt project supplied as an example with Android Studio to send RSSI values back to the main activity for display each time a characteristic is read.  I have created a new intent filter, but the receiver never receives the intent.  I have tried adding it to the manifest file, but that didn't work either.

Here is the Service code:

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
...
public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
public final static String RSSI_DATA_AVAILABLE =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.RSSI_DATA_AVAILABLE";
public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";
public final static String EXTRA_RSSI =
        "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_RSSI";

@Override
public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status) {
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        mBluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi();
    }
}

@Override
public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RSSI, String.valueOf(rssi));
        intent.setAction(RSSI_DATA_AVAILABLE);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

And the Activity:

```
public class DeviceControlActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = true;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = false;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                clearUI();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
                displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                displayData(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA));
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.RSSI_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                updateRssi(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_RSSI));
            }
        }
        };
...
```

}

Answer:

I had to add the action to this method in the Activity:

```
    private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter() {
    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.RSSI_DATA_AVAILABLE);
    return intentFilter;
}
```

Comment: where are you registering the BroadcastReceiver ?

Comment: not sure.  Android noob.  It doesn't show up in any manifest files in the example code.

Comment: did you create an IntentFilter ?

Comment: Only in the service class: `public final static String RSSI_DATA_AVAILABLE = "com.example.bluetooth.le.RSSI_DATA_AVAILABLE";`  And then I check for it in the onReceive function: `else if (BluetoothLeService.RSSI_DATA_AVAILABLE.equals(action)) {
                updateRssi(intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_RSSI));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

override `onResume` in your `Activity`, create an `IntentFilter`, adding your custom actions, and register the broadcast receiver.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
// call addAction for every action you want to receive in your BroadcastReceiver
filter.addAction(BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED);
```

and then register it with

```
registerReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver, filter);
```

override onPause and call `unregeisterReceiver`

```
 unregisterReceiver(mGattUpdateReceiver);
```

Comment: Thanks that was it.  All I had to do was add the new action to this method:
`private static IntentFilter makeGattUpdateIntentFilter()`

Comment: I call `registerReceiver` at `onCreate` at `Activity`, and `unregistedReceiver` at `onDestroy`. The receiver JobService gets triggered okay at broadcasts, for my custom action name.